# Error VS Code Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vscode

Hola tengo un error para ejecutar codigo python en VS Code.

Version Python: Python 3.8.4

He reinstalado el pluggin de python (Microsoft), borrado y vuelto a crear la carpeta .vscode
Aún así me sigue dando la falla.

el interprete de Python, y PyPy funcionan bien, si corro el código en sublime text funciona bien, también he revisado las variables del entorno y están completas las ubicaciones en el path.

No recuerdo haber cambiado nada en la conf. (Tenia algún tiempo sin usar VSCode)

Código:

```
print("Hola")
```

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\Juan\Desktop>  & 'C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Juan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.101144\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '55125' '--' 'c:\Users\Juan\Desktop\aa.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Juan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.101144\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 43, in 
<module>
    from debugpy.server import cli
  File "c:\Users\Juan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.101144\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import debugpy._vendored.force_pydevd  # noqa
  File "c:\Users\Juan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.101144\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\_vendored\force_pydevd.py", line 40, in <module>
    preimport('pydevd', [
  File "c:\Users\Juan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.101144\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\_vendored\__init__.py", line 128, in preimport
    import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "c:\Users\Juan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.101144\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_plugins\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
PS C:\Users\Juan\Desktop>
```

Gracias.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Usa este comando: `sudo pip install python-dotenv`

Normalmente este error se suele producir porque no faltan módulos o ficheros para manejar los entornos, el módulo `python-dotenv` se encarga de ello.

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por ayudar. He buscado sobre el paquete que me indicas porque no lo conocía y lo instalé. Pero realmente cual seria su utilidad en mi caso o mas bien como lo implemento? te lo pregunto porque ejecuté el archivo en sublime (solo con la funcion print) y funciona bien, no debería faltar ningún modulo me parece.

Comment: El error te pone concretamente que ```AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'```. Es decir que ese módulo no tiene dicho atributo, eso puede deberse a una mala instalación del paquete. El paquete no debes de usarlo, es un paquete que utiliza internamente python para funcionar. Aunque puede que provenga de otro sitio el error y esta medida que te he comentado, no te lo solucione. En su día a mí me funcionó!

Comment: Hola Amigo, ya lo solucioné, Algún paquete instalado con pip, estaba haciendo el conflicto (Curiosamente solo con el Debugger de Vs. Code). No se exactamente cual era, pues los borre todos y ahora me encuentro trabajando en entornos virtuales para prevenir. Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Me alegro de que al final hayas encontrado una solución! :)